# Git And GitHub with my first react js project

Tags: git, github

how could I upload my first project on github throught using the git commands

I'm trying to uplaod my react project on the github through the git commands

and I wanna see my react first project on github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through this video as it does a nice job of explaining all the steps you need to getting started with GIT: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRZGeaHPoaw

To give you a quick guide:

- Navigate to your project root via a terminal that supports git - e.g. https://git-scm.com/downloads for windows or on Linux/mac the native terminal should work fine.
- `git init && git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/main`
- `git add .`
- `git commit -m "initial commit"`
- `git remote add origin <REMOTE_URL>`   - you will get this URL from your project's GitHub page.
- `git push origin main`

A word of caution - normally you would not want to use "git add ." as this just adds everything to a commit:

```
git add -p [filename] instead of git add .
```

The first command will allow you to interactively view a diff of changes and add code one line at a time.